# Getting histogram datetime list python

Tags: python, datetime, histogram, intervals

I tried to find number of tweets about a keyword according to datetime. 
I gather relative tweets and dates from my dataset.I have a datetime list as shown below.

> ```
> 2018-06-22 00:47:25.000000
> 2018-06-22 00:47:34.000000
> 2018-06-22 00:52:55.000000
> 2018-06-22 00:59:43.000000
> 2018-06-22 01:00:14.000000
> 2018-06-22 01:00:26.000000
> 2018-06-22 01:00:32.000000
> 2018-06-22 01:00:58.000000
> ...
> ```

I want to create an histogram different intervals.

output of 1 minute interval:

```
2018-06-22 00:47-00:48  =2
2018-06-22 00:48-00:49  =0
2018-06-22 00:49-00:50  =0
...
2018-06-22 00:52-00:53  =1
...
2018-06-22 00:59-01:00  =1
2018-06-22 01:00-01:01  =4
```

output of 5 minute interval:

```
2018-06-22 00:47-00:52  =2
2018-06-22 00:52-00:57  =1
2018-06-22 00:57-01:02  =5
```

"Parsing dates and count intervals manually" it seems hard. how can i do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it. I use panda and numpy. 
Give two datetime for the range and set the freq.

```
intervals = pd.date_range('2018-06-22 00:00:00','2018-06-23 00:00:00', freq='60min')
```

Due to count the num of tweets in correct interval, create a array filled with zeros

```
count_interval = np.zeros(intervals.size)
```

Time of tweets store in "tDate" list, searching suitable interval for the time of each tweet with code below.

```
for tDate in tweetDates:
    index = 0
    for inter in intervals:
        if (pd.Timestamp(tDate) >= intervals[index]) & (pd.Timestamp(tDate) < intervals[index + 1]):
            count_interval[index] = count_interval[index]+1
            break
        else:
            index = index+1
```

After that, plot with matplotlib library.

```
plt.plot(intervals, count_interval, linewidth=1.0)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break it in 3 steps: start  and end of the interval  , then make  the delta with function from datime,

```
import datetime
date= '2018-06-22 00:47-00:52'
start= date[0:-6]
print( start) 
start_parsed = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').strftime("%d/%m/%y - %H:%M")
```

Hope it would help 
do the same for the end of the interval and use from the same library the delta function,